# How to define default 'program listing' title and parameters in Lyx

Tags: listings, lyx, python

I'm using LyX software and need to embed python code snippets and the option I found is to put snippet in a file and then use: insert> file> Child Document ----> choose the snippet file ----> set include type to "Program Listing", set label to e.g. py:xx and caption to e.g. "My Python code" and define parameters such as backgroundcolor etc.

Firstly, how can I change the title of the object from Listing 1: to e.g. Snippet 1?

Secondly, how can I set parameters globally for all Program listing widgets so that I won't have to redefine them every time?

Thirdly, please let me know if you know of a better way to embed Python code (I'm using PyDev on Eclipse IDE for python programming).

Comment: I don't know in Lyx, but the LaTeX way to do it, is to add the line `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Snippet}` in the preamble...

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. From karlkoeller's comment: Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, add

   ```
   \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Snippet}}
   ```

   The `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary because LyX 2.1 adds `\usepackage{listings}` *after* the stuff that is added to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble, so `\lstlistingname` is not defined at that time. You could alternatively do

   ```
   \usepackage{listings}
   \renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Snippet}
   ```

   though this means `listings` is loaded twice.
2. Caption and label has to be set for each listing of course, but the general style can be defined in Document --> Settings --> Listings:

   [image]

Comment: Is there a change regarding `\lstlistingname`? It doesn't seem to work for me. Using LyX Version 2.1.1 (Wednesday, July 2, 2014).

Comment: @NikosAlexandris The problem that LyX adds `\usepackage{listings}` after the user specified preamble stuff, so `\lstlistingname` isn't defined at the time. Use `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Snippet}}` instead.

Comment: Perfect, issue resolved. Maybe the answer deserves an edit/update?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I intended to do so, but I didn't have time earlier. It's updated now.

Comment: I was about to do it (for you) but, sometimes, I feel like not touching other people's work. Maybe I was wrong hesitating. Thanks.